# How to retrieve all non zero values and their respective column headings into different text boxes

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried the following code but facing problem in looping for next column and its respective value into next text box/Label. (for this problem please take non zero values as 0)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i As Long, lastrow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim fcolumn As Long
Dim lcolumn As Long
Set ws = Worksheets("md")
lastrow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows,SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

fcolumn = 9
lcolumn = 50

'defining the rows to be search from
For i = 2 To lastrow
fcolumn = fcolumn + 1
If ws.Cells(i, "A").Value = Val(Me.TextBox1) Then
' Get non zero values from the working row
If Sheets("md").Cells(i, fcolumn).Value <> 0 Then
Me.Label1 = ws.Cells(2, fcolumn)
Me.TextBox1 = Sheets("md").Cells(i, fcolumn).Value

End If
If Sheets("md").Cells(i, fcolumn).Value <> 0 Then
Me.Label2 = ws.Cells(2, fcolumn)
Me.TextBox1 = Sheets("md").Cells(i, fcolumn).Value
End If



Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To loop columns, add a `For` loop before this line: `For i = 2 To lastrow`

For loop should be something like

```
For fcolumn = 9 to lcolumn
```

As suggestion, please indent your code to be easy readable.